# How to open instagram launcher activity from another app

Tags: java, android, instagram-api

```
 Intent hashtagIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("com.instagram.android"));
            startActivity(hashtagIntent);
```

I'm trying to launch the instagram app from my app.
I have tried the code above, but it failed to open the Instagram app.

Comment: you try to start the app package, while you need to start an Activity. @VishalChhodwani answer shows how to get launcher activity from app package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This**

It will help you definitely

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
if (launchIntent != null)
{
    try
    {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) // in case Instagram not installed in your device
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Comment: what if i want the app to open a specific user account after it launches?